# Interpolate zoo object with missing Dates

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, zoo

I have a climate time series with missing Dates (not missing values). For example:

```
n = 15
full.dates = seq(Sys.Date(), by = 'day', length = n)
serie.dates = full.dates[c(1:10, 12, 15)] # missing 11, 13, 14
y = rnorm(n)

require(zoo)    
serie = zoo(y, serie.dates)
```

How can i 'fill' (using interpolation) these missing points, given the 'full.dates' vector?
Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Merge with an "empty" object that has all the dates you want, then use `na.approx` (or `na.spline`, etc.) to fill in the missing values.

```
x <- merge(serie, zoo(,seq(start(serie),end(serie),by="day")), all=TRUE)
x <- na.approx(x)
```

Comment: Try also na.locf : it takes the most recent value before a given NA