# Financial time series R - defining date

Tags: r, date, import

I am a total beginner in R so I would really appreciate your quick tip. 
I have imported data from csv - financial time series: index returns, with a daily frequency, though with some missing values when the market was closed. What I have found is the ts class, where you need to define the stable frequency. Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to So. Unfortunately, it's not very clear what we should help you with. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: If what you want to do is to fill in those missing dates, the zoo [merge/na.approx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114834/interpolate-zoo-object-with-missing-dates) routine should work.