# R - approximate missing month values using zoo package

Tags: r, zoo

Consider code:

```
library('zoo')

data <- c(1, 2, 4, 6)
dates <- c("2016-11-01", "2016-12-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-04-01");
z1 <- zoo(data, as.yearmon(dates))
z2 <- na.approx(z1)
```

Variable `z2` looks like this:

```
nov 2016 dec 2016 feb 2017 apr 2017 
       1        2        4        6
```

But I need `z2` to be similar to this:

```
nov 2016 dec 2016 jan 2017 feb 2017 mar 2017 apr 2017 
       1        2        3        4        5        6
```

I just need to approximate values for months where value is missing. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: possibly like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114834/interpolate-zoo-object-with-missing-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new `as.zoo` argument, `calendar`, in zoo 1.8 (which defaults to TRUE so we don't  have to specify it) we can just convert the input to `"ts"` and then back to `"zoo"` again applying `na.approx` after that:

```
na.approx(as.zoo(as.ts(z2)))
## Nov 2016 Dec 2016 Jan 2017 Feb 2017 Mar 2017 Apr 2017 
##        1        2        3        4        5        6
```

With prior versions of zoo we can do the same but manually convert the index back to `"yearmon"`:

```
na.approx(aggregate(as.zoo(as.ts(z2)), as.yearmon, c))
```

**magrittr**

Using zoo with magrittr these can be expressed as the following pipelines, respectively:

```
library(magrittr)

z2 %>% as.ts %>% as.zoo %>% na.approx

z2 %>% as.ts %>% as.zoo %>% aggregate(as.yearmon, c) %>% na.approx
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using just `na.approx` and base R:

```
#add your data and dates together
df <- data.frame(data, dates = as.Date(dates))
#create all dates using seq
new_dates <- data.frame(dates = seq(as.Date(dates[1]), as.Date(dates[4]), by = 'month'))
#merge the two and then na.approx
new_df <- merge(new_dates, df, by = 'dates', all.x = TRUE)
na.approx(new_df$data)
```

Out:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```